# I-Report 4.1.1 exporting excel sheet issue

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

When i am exporting my report from jasper, it is getting exported in .xlsx but when the same jrxml is exported from java code it is not getting exported in .xlsx.

The java code is as follows:-

```
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, sheetnames );
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output); 
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

This code is working for another jrxml which is getting exported in .xlsx

Answer (score 1):

hey buddy u need to use xlsx exporter,

see the below example.

```
JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OFFSET_X, 0);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, destination);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();
```

I think you're using `JRXlsEporter` instead of `JRXlsxExporter`
PS: notice extra x before exporter :D

Comment: I used the xlsx exporter but the excel is  getting corrupted when m exporting it in xlsx from java code

Comment: ok then my guess is its a multi sheet export and you are not adding prints (jasper prints) properly...

Comment: Its a single sheet export and there is only one print object...!!
I deleted all the fields from all bands means i tried to export a empty jrxml from java code but still m getting the same error

Comment: OutputStream output
   = new FileOutputStream(new File(reportVO.getxFilePath()));
   JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter(); 
   exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, sheetnames );
   exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
   exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output); 
   exporterXLS.exportReport();

Comment: well i dont exactly use Output for output, as u can see in my code i simply pass the file name with desired output file name as string i.e. "temp.xlsx"..!!

PS: where are you providing JasperPrint here..!!??? i cant see any..

Comment: do you log your application??
if you do can you post the full log over here??

Comment: The report is getting exported when i am xporting it in XLSX but when i am openning it ..its giving me an error...!!